# ExtJS and buttons

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I'm novice in ExtJS ... but

I can't solve my problem with two buttons, let's say **[B1]** and **[B2]**.
On simple toolbar I want to have two buttons on the SAME place
respectively on something (let's say 20 pcx from the left on the 
toolbar) displayed alternately **[B1]** or **[B2]** on the same position. 
Buttons are defined as:

```
xtype: 'toolbar',
dock: 'bottom',
height: 30,
items: [
```

**[B1]** is filefield button:

```
  xtype: 'filefield',  
   itemId: 'FFId',
   buttonOnly: true,
   ...
```

**[B2]** button (in fact used as pull down menu button):

```
   xtype: 'button',                      
   iconAlign: 'right',
   ...
]
```

When buttons are simple buttons boyh situation is the same. I tried 
to hide/show them the following way:

1. on the base of hidden property and method `setVisible()` they are no 
   in the same place, they are displayed "side by side" (I mean e.g. 
   [B1] place is empty and on the right side [B2] is displayed)
2. on the base of `style: 'visibility: ...'` - the same situation
3. on the base of `style: 'display: ...'` almost good, both buttons
   are displayed the same place but (left 20 pcx the toolbar) 
   lower in the toolbar so I see half of both of them

Have you any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the property `hidden: true`.

And for changing the state after it is rendered use the functions `.hide()`, `.show()` or if you want to use the same function for both `.setHidden(boolInput)` where `boolInput` is `true` if you want to hide the button, and `false` if you want to show it.

Edit for clarification:

I assumed you to be wanting to show only one button at a time, and have which ever button is showing at any given time be displayed in the same location. Is that what you wanted, or something different?

Here is a working example of what I understand you are looking for:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/nvn

Answer (score 0):

For your third option `style: 'display: ...'`, you can try set margin and padding configuration to adjust the position of buttons.